# Is there a simple function to make a string of a list of chars?

Tags: string, list, haskell, char

I want to make a String from a list of chars [Lettre]

For example, 
       ['1', '2', '3', 'W', '5', '5', 'W', '3'] 
should be printed as (1, 2, 3, W, 5, 5, W, 3)

Now, I use

```
data Lettre = Steen Char

makeString :: [Lettre] -> String
makeString [] = ""
makeString [Steen(x)] = x:[]
makeString (Steen(x):xs) = (x:", ") ++ makeString xs
```

but I feel like this could be easier.

Is there a simple function, something like toString? I tried using some functions I knew, but it doesn't seem to work on my code, so I keep using makeString.

A big thanks to anyone who could help me out :)

Comment: A string is already a list of characters in Haskell. It's just a type alias.

Comment: Nevermind,I see I misunderstood your question. You want to format the string in a particular way, with commas between each character and surrounding parentheses? But I don't know what `Steen` is, or `Lettre` (is it a type alias for `Char`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a list of a characters, you could use `intersperse`, but that only allows single-character separators.

```
> "(" ++ intersperse ',' "123W55W3" ++ ")"
"(1,2,3,W,5,5,W,3)"
```

For a multicharacter separator like `", "`, you can use `intercalate`, but then you need a list of `String`, not a list of `Char`.

The solution is to lift each character into a string, then use `intercalate`.

```
> "(" ++ intercalate ", " (map pure "123W55W3") ++ ")"
"(1, 2, 3, W, 5, 5, W, 3)"
```

---

I'm assuming the input is an actual `[Char]`/`String` value; if you actually have some more complicated `Char` wrapper, like

```
newtype Lettre = Steen Char
```

as could be inferred from your attempt, use instead something like

```
makeString :: [Lettre] -> String
makeString xs = "(" ++ intercalate ", " [[x] | Steen x <- xs] ++ ")"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but how do I do that when the chars are in a list?

Comment: `type String = [Char]`; `"foo"` is just syntactic sugar for `['f', 'o', 'o']`.

Comment: In fact, `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` and `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` are defined in `Data.List`, and work on strings *because* a string is just a list of `Char`.

Comment: hey, thank you for answering. Saddly the code tells me that it    "Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Char’ "

Comment: The difficult thing here is that the chars are here in a list. And that part is just giving an error in my head

Comment: @ElzineBurger Could we see the full error? Your code seems to be expecting a string somewhere, but is being passed a char.

Comment: Dobbelen.hs:154:36: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the expression: x
      In the second argument of ‘intercalate’, namely
        ‘[x | Steen x <- xs]’
      In the expression: intercalate ", " [x | Steen x <- xs]
    |
154 | maakString xs =  intercalate ", " [x | Steen x <- xs]     |                                    ^

Comment: You need to provide the definition of `Lettre` (in your *question*, not in a comment).

Comment: OK, it's fixed now. I stupidly forgot to wrap `x` in a list in the list comprehension, so I was passing a `[Char]`, not a `[String]`, to `intercalate ", "`.

Comment: Uhm, so how do I do this? I tried `intercalate ", " [x | Steen x <- xs]` which doesnt work. Into what do I change this code?

Comment: Aah oke. Thank you so much!